# Can you add more yeast into a batch of cider if you think you've killed it?

Tags: yeast, carbonation, cider

Ok, so I’m really new to this
I started off making cider
Since I juiced my own apples, I used the method of pasteurisation that kills off wild yeast by heating the gallon of juice on a stove while adding sugar
I allowed the cider to cool, and then added the yeast
It’s only been about 16 hours, and tiny bubbles are in the water of the vapour lock, but I’m worried I might not have let the cider cool down enough before the yeast was added, as it only cooled for half an hour
Can I add more yeast to the mix if in a few days it isn't showing any signs of fermentation? Or do you thing the batch will be alright, or should I just chuck it?

Comment: what kind of yeast did you use? How hot did you pastuerize at?

Answer (score 2):

no worries, you can add more yeast if fermentation hasn't started after a day or two. In the future don't add yeast until it has cooled to 70-75F or below.